# Storing images to firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to store an image that I downloaded from google to firebase storage I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm getting this error "    **An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.**"

```
E/UploadTask: could not locate file for uploading:file:///images
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: /images: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /images: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

this my code:

```java
private void saveImgToStorage() {
    if (imageUri != null) {
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("images"));
        imgRef = storageReference.child("images");
        imgRef.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot > () {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "STORED IMAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "FAILED TO STORE IMAGE " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Storage Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("images"));
```

This says that you have a file called `images`, which you then want to upload to Firebase. The error message you get indicates that no such file can be found:

> E/UploadTask: could not locate file for uploading:file:///images

I recommend checking out:

- [Access a local file with file:// in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332261/access-a-local-file-with-file-in-android)
- [How can I read a text file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-in-android)
- [How do I read the file content from the Internal storage - Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768191/how-do-i-read-the-file-content-from-the-internal-storage-android-app)

And more from this search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bandroid%5d%5bjava%5d%20read%20local%20file